# If I truncate a table, should I also add indexes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a rails application with MYSQL and I've created a migration for adding indexes to tables.
Also I have a rake task that truncates some of the tables and writes data.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{Model.table_name}")
```

Do I need to add indexes again after truncate ?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The table is dropped and then re-created again (including any indexes and constraints)

Comment: though it seems that some people have had trouble with indexes NOT being re-created when truncating, for example here: http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/652228-index-disabled-after-truncate